# Images from parent folder (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I created a mobile version of my web site. This version is just a sub directory of the page, so the structure is:

- root

  - images
  - ...
  - mobile

    - index.php
  - index.php

All page data is read from the same database as the desktop version uses. 
Images are using the path: /images/    [image] .jpg

The problem now: the path is wrong for the mobile version. It needs to be /../images/ ...

Is there a way to fix this using .htaccess ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add below text into /root/.htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 /mobile/images/(.*) /images/$1
```

Comment: Did not work.. I need all images from the database to be loaded from ../images ! Now they are loaded from /mobile/images (which doesn't exist!)